# Cambiar el color de las etiquetas de datos en JavaFX

Tags: java, java-swing, javafx, javafx-css

Estoy buscando la forma de cambiar el color de las etiquetas de datos en un gráfico de barras. El primer valor se muestra dentro de la barra y los demás se muestran fuera. He intentado cambiarlo mediante la configuración CSS, pero no ha funcionado. ¿Cómo puedo lograrlo?

[image: Valores]

Comment: podrías compartir tu código? tal vez así sea más fácil corregirlo

Comment: Para agregarlo primero hay que saber como lograstes colocar el texto en la barra porque normalmente el viene sin eso, entonces el nodo que usastes para lograrlo es a quien tienes que aplicarle el efecto del css. Pero como dice Ruslan, seria de mucha mas utilidad que mostraras el codigo.